# Google App Engine - When I want to store a byte array as one of the fields of my entity, do I have to specify it as of type Blob?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Google App Engine - When I want to store a byte array as one of the fields of my entity class, do I have to specify it as of type `Blob` or `ShortBlob` instead of `byte[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to store a Byte array you have two choices:

1. com.google.appengine.api.datastore.ShortBlob : short byte string, < 500 bytes
2. com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob: long byte string (not orderable)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you have to.  You can always convert to `Blob/ShortBlob` for storage only and convert it back into a `byte[]` immediately after you restore it.

Comment: And yes, that breaks the "POJO" paradigm of the AppEngine/DataStore. The main advantages of using POJO as datastore model is to reuse the same model classes in other parts of the application. Using Blob induce (another) dependency from your domain to appengine.